# How to execute an SSIS package through Excel Macro when SQL Server BIDS is installed on a remote machine and NOT locally?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, vba

I have a typical case here when I don't have SQL Server BIDS (Business Intelligence Development Studio) application installed on my PC and I want to run/execute a .dtsx package file using an excel macro which will launch the BIDS instance residing on a CITRIX server (remote machine) and use the package configuration file (XML config file) to execute it.

I NEITHER have SQL Server installed on my PC from where I could atlease create a SQL Agent job and schedule the package execution programmatically or use the Command line statements to execute the package from DOS prompt.

Please help me out as I need to find a solution to this ASAP. Thanks!!

Comment: I know it doesn't help you but if you need to execute an SSIS package then why are you not allowed the tools to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the server is not *so* remote that you can't talk to it at all, the usual approach would be to set up an agent job to run the package, then find a way to trigger the job.  There's a good discussion of this in [this Microsoft article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx#Y386).

The most straight-forward way requires opening a DB connection to the server and running sp_start_job (which means you need credentials which will allow this), as described in the article - but there's obviously multiple other ways to fire off a job.